# Accessible file upload in React (no drag/drop, no jQuery)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, file-upload, accessibility

I am trying to find an accessible file upload method for React that doesn't rely on jQuery (I am not using it) but does rely on Fetch (async).

Everything I've found thus far seems to be drag and drop type components or uses jQuery's `$.ajax` methods. I feel like there's got to be a way to send a file with other form fields.

The front end is React with vanilla JavaScript. I've got a custom API that sends data to my back end asynchronously with Fetch. My back end uses Multer to gather form data. My form sends with `multipart/form-data`.

I've tried a few things, including adjusting the headers when sending from React to my back end, but either only the body comes through (no files) or nothing at all comes through.

I could get this to work by directly sending to my Express server, but I don't want to expose my API routes in the HTML, and I'm hoping to avoid the page refresh which would make this form stand out from everything else in my app. I have decided against using jQuery because I am able to do pretty much everything without it and I don't want to add the weight of the library just for the one method.

Accessibility is key (drag and drop components generally aren't accessible for obvious reasons) so I'm hoping to use a standard `input file` element here.

Thanks to anyone and all in advance.

Comment: You may use `react-cropper` https://github.com/roadmanfong/react-cropper.

Comment: you can use a third party http library like https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios which is much smaller than jquery (and imo easier to use). I think it is worth the dependency. I have been playing with an implementation myself, here is my (still work in progress) implementation of using axios to submit the file to a backend API: https://github.com/erik-sn/tagmap/blob/master/js/src/components/uploader.js#L105

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately `react-cropper` wasn't quite what I was going for.

I did end up switching from Isomorphic Fetch to Axios though. Not that it solved the problem, but it looks more configurable. Thanks for that suggestion.

I'm currently toying with using `FileReader` to convert the image to Base64, send it along with the other form JSON, and re-convert on the server. This works, only with smaller images. I'm looking up ways to alter the limit of how much data can be sent in a JSON object.